# How to change the format of the DateTime/GetLastWriteTime?

Tags: c#

so i need to list a bunch of filenames and their LastWriteTime. The following Code is how I get my LastWriteTime which i print later.

```
DateTime lDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileNames[x]);
```

before doing so I get a bunch of fileNames out of a specified Directory.

In the end it prints the GetLastWriteTime as followed:

```
20.04.2017
```

but I need it with - instead of . :

```
20-04-2017
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Please excuse my english, as I am not a native Speaker. I hope my Problem is explained clear enough. If not, I will try to give further Explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the .ToString();
`string lDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileNames[x]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Comment: it brings up the following error: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Use a string, instead of a  DateTime<br/>
string lDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileNames[x]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: @joshi422 use ToString only when you need to print it

Comment: S.Petrosov is right, it only works when i print it. thanks to both of you:)

Answer (score 1):

`File.GetLastWriteTime` returns `DateTime` object you can you `ToString("tiem_pattern")` to get date and time in format you want. In your case you need this one:

```
File.GetLastWriteTime(fileNames[x]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```